# CMake resources in source code for build and install

Tags: installation, cmake, build, resources

This has been on my mind for years. It is about using resource files with CMake in code such that they can be accessed when running in the build directory and when installed.

Say you have files necessary to run your program in a top-level directory called res. It contains res/file1.txt and res/file2.txt. You build this program and the resources are copied to the build directory from which the program can be run during development. Then, the program is installed with the resources into /usr/share/my_program or something and the program runs by accessing those files. The question is what to do in the source code so that the same code works when running from the build directory and when installed. I've seen several different answers for how to handle resources but each seems to have a flaw:

1. The program searches in some preconfigured absolute directory such as CMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX/share/my_program and must be installed first to run, not ideal for easy use during development.
2. Finding some way to use relative paths to the binary but I don't see how this would work since the build tree will not mirror the installed file paths, being installed to the bin and share directories.
3. Differentiating between the two with a CMake variable so that it searches for a relative path in one scenario or the installed location with another. This could possibly just be the debug/release variable. It would also require rerunning CMake before installing to rebuild with the new resource paths.
4. Baking the files into the executable. Seems uneccessary when dealing with most resources since they could just be opened instead and may be inconvenient with large directories of files.

Is one of these the best solution? Is there something I'm not misunderstanding? I've always been under the impression programs should be able to be run from the build directory before installing to see if they work. If possible, I would like to know what both the CMake and C/C++ code would look like, such as `open("my_resource_location");` and `my_cmake_command()`. Most answers I've seen relating to resources don't include both.

Comment: The problem is hardly related to CMake: the only thing which CMake changes in executables on installation is RPATH. All other changes you should perform manually (via additional scripting). The problem is also hardly related to the build tool you use. It is **fully up to a developer**, whether he wants to support running executable which is just built. From my point of view, requirement to install the program before use it doesn't harm development a lot. It even makes development easier, as your program needs to work only in a single scenario (installed).

Comment: With a bit of work, you can set up your CMake build tree to mirror your install directory.  Look into the CMake variable CMAKE_RUNTIME_OUTPUT_DIRECTORY.

Answer (score 1):

It seems to me that what you are looking for is a *relocatable build*.

One way to achieve this in CMake is to use configuration files to incorporate resource paths in your code. I have prepared a minimal and reproducible example to give you an idea of how it works.

First, imagine you have the following program structure on disk:

```
main
  CMakeLists.txt
  main.cpp
data
  CMakeLists.txt
  Resources.h.in            (Thats the configuration file)
  resource.txt
```

The `resource.txt` file only contains a string. The program simply opens that file, reads its content and displays it to the terminal. So you have something like:

```cpp
#include <fstream>
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

#include <Resources.h>

const std::string MY_FILE = "/resource.txt";

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    std::string line;
    std::ifstream myfile (RESOURCE_PATH + MY_FILE);
    if(myfile.is_open())
    {
        while(std::getline(myfile,line))
        {
            std::cout << line << '\n';
        }
        
        myfile.close();
    }
    else
    {
        std::cout << "Unable to open file";
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Note that this file `#include`s a `Resources.h` file, but that this file does not exist in our project. However, we have a `Resources.h.in` configuration file that CMake will turn into a `Resources.h` file on generation. This generated file will then contain the resource path we need inside the `RESOURCE_PATH` variable. Here is what the configuration file contains:

```cpp
#define RESSOURCE_PATH "@CMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX@/@CMAKE_INSTALL_DATADIR@"
```

A simple `#define` with this strange @something@ notation. On generation, CMake will make the appropriate substitution and write the result to `Resource.h`, which we can then consume. The main `CMakeLists.txt` file is pretty straight forward:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.10)

project(example)

# Sets up classic installation directories. However,
# you can override them:
include(GNUInstallDirs)

add_subdirectory(data)
add_subdirectory(main)
```

I use the `GNUInstallDirs`, which populates variables such as `CMAKE_INSTALL_DATADIR`, for convinience. The `main/CMakeLists.txt` file:

```
add_executable(example main.cpp)

configure_file("${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/Ressources.h.in" "Ressources.h")
target_include_directories(example
  PRIVATE ${CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR}
)

install(
  TARGETS example
  DESTINATION ${CMAKE_INSTALL_BINDIR}
)
```

This is where the configuration file is set up. The `target_include_directories` just below is added for CMake to be able to find the generated `Resource.h` file, which will reside in the build directory. Finally, the `data/CMakeLists.txt` file:

```
install(
  FILES resource.txt 
  DESTINATION ${CMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX}/${CMAKE_INSTALL_DATADIR}
)
```

only has a simple installation instruction. From there, you can install as usual. Simply create a build directory and use CMake as usual. For example, if the build directory is located at the same level as the project:

```sh
mkdir ../build
cd ../build
cmake ../project
make
sudo make install
```

Since by default (on Linux) we have:

```
CMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX=/usr/local
CMAKE_INSTALL_BINDIR=bin
CMAKE_INSTALL_DATADIR=share
```

The program will be installed to `/usr/local/bin` and the resource to `/usr/local/share`. Note that the `Resource.h` file will give you the correct path once generated by CMake. Whats is nice now, however, is that you can modify the value of `CMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX` to point to somewhere else by calling CMake like so (for example, this could be a dev build directory):

```
cmake -DCMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX=/home/someone/example ../project
```

and you will have these values instead:

```
CMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX=/home/someone/example
CMAKE_INSTALL_BINDIR=bin
CMAKE_INSTALL_DATADIR=share
```

The `Resources.h` file will also be updated to point to the right location, and your resource will still be found.